# POST data to redirect page fail

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I was totally confused by the following situation...

**situation**

> post data from *a.php* to *b.php* and redirect to *b.php*...but fail

**CODE**
- *a.php*

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#submit').click(function() {
          $.ajax({
            url: 'b.php',    
            dataType: 'html',
            type: 'POST',
            data: { 
              value: $('#value').val()
            },
            error: function(xhr) {
              console.log('ajax went wrong!');
            },
            success: function(response) {
              console.log(response);
              window.location.href = "b.php";      
            }
          });

        });
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    value: <input type="text" id="value">
  </body>
</html>
```

**CODE**
- *b.php*

```
<?php
  echo $_REQUEST['value'];
?>
```

*a.php* can get the right response from *b.php* without redirect function. However, once I include the statement `window.location.href = "b.php";`, *a.php* will redirect to *b.php* but without printing anything.
Why is this situation happening?
Is there any solution to fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm missing something, but why don't you just POST the data to the page normally (e.g. by form submission). Do you have to use ajax and then a redirect?

Comment: @Toddish : I plan to handle the _value_ on _b.php_ instead of _a.php_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can't pass data between to pages in this way. Posting data to b.php and redirecting to it - are two different requests.

if you want to pass data via redirecting - use GET params:

```
window.location.href = "b.php?value="+$('#value').val();
```

Also form submission directly to b.php can help you.

```
<form action="b.php" method="post">
    <input name="value" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you! Your solution is quite elegant! But which way will you suggest to handle this kind of case? It seems easier to maintain if I handle all the events within a script.

Comment: @user2364801: If don't need any specific data preprocessing then html-form would be better solution. But if data has to modified before being sent to another page - js is OK. Both ways have a right to exist. Which is better - depends on requirements.

Answer (score 1):

You just need a `<form>` so that whenever you click on `submit` button your all form data will be transferred to `b.php` (YOU WILL AUTOMATICALLY BE REDIRECTED TO `b.php` page) and you can there access `$_POST['value']`. That's very simple. No need to do `$.ajax` call.

```
<form id="myFrm" name="myFrm" method="post" action="b.php">
    value: <input type="text" id="value" name="value">
    <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your ajax code is working. It is calling the url b.php and printing the value to output. However, the result is not what you expect.

When you made the ajax call and send the data in the form, the evaluation of b.php will be in response when ajax request is successful. Try to make the following change :

From

```
window.location.href = "b.php";
```

to

```
alert(response);
```

You will see what you send in the input in a message box. Follow your code adapted. Note I added a button to make the call:

index.php

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#submit').click(function() {
          $.ajax({
            url: 'ajax.php',    
            dataType: 'html',
            type: 'POST',
            data: { 
              value: $('#value').val()
            },
            error: function(xhr) {
              console.log('ajax went wrong!');
            },
            success: function(response) {
                alert(response);
                console.log(response);
              //window.location.href = "b.php";      
            }
          });

        });
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    value: <input type="text" id="value">
    <input type=button id="submit" value=go>
  </body>
</html>
```

ajax.php

```
<?php
echo $_REQUEST['value'];
?>
```

This is the ajax approach. But if you need only pass the value in the form to b.php, you do not need ajax. Just create a form and use b.php as it action like this:

index.php

```
    <html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form method="POST" action="b.php">
    value: <input type="text" id="value" name="value">
    <input type=submit  value=go>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

b.php

```
<?php
echo $_REQUEST['value'];
?>
```

Note the changes I made in your html.

Comment: Thanks for your answer which let me saw the request I send!

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this one, i think this will help you.
Here i create two pages.
one is a.php and another page is b.php
```

a.php

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function() {
        var abc='';
        $('#submit').click(function() {
        var abc=$('#abc').val();
          $.ajax({
            url: 'b.php',
            dataType: 'html',
            type: 'POST',
            data: { 
              value: abc
            },
            error: function(xhr) {
              console.log('ajax went wrong!');
            },
            success: function(response) {
              console.log(response);
                var stateObj = { foo: "b" };
                history.pushState(stateObj, "page 2", "b.php?value="+response);
                $('#hid').hide();
                $('#res').html(response);
            }
          });

        });
      });
    </script>

    <html>
    <body>
         <div id="hid">
            Value: <input type="text" id="abc" /> <input type="button" id="submit" value="Get Value" /><br>
        </div>
    <div id="res"></div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

b.php

```
<?php
echo $_REQUEST['value'];
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

use

$_post['value'] instead of $_request['value']

Comment: how does this help to "save" post data for new `get` request?

Comment: but the data we are getting is through ajax call post method to b.php ,so to print that he has to use $_post instead of $_request

Comment: $_request contains $_post. by default it contains $_get, $_post and $_cookie. using $_post is just way to specify that you expect data sent by `POST` method. but it is not the problem of OP.

Comment: Yes hes posting data using POST method, but after that its just a plain redirect without any data being posted, so `$_POST` will be empty when redirected.